# In collatz sequence like 34,17..2,1,print 40 characters per line

Tags: c

From list of collatz sequence that are like 34,17,52,26,13...4,2,1.I want to print 40 characters for each line like "50, 25, 76, 38, 19, 58, 29, 88, 44, 22," will be first line of 40 characters and then next line and should stop when last number are 4, 2, 1
I am unable to stop the program when 4, 2, 1 sequence is encountered.

I have first created the required sequence of numbers. Post that tried to print numbers by for loop with while condition of 1.

```
int length;
int *ptr;
int i = 50, j = 0;
for (i; i >= 2; )
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        i = i / 2;
    }
    else if (i % 2 != 0)
    {
        i = (3 * i) + 1;
    }
    ptr[j] = i;
    printf("Total Value: %d, \n", ptr[j]);
    j++;
}
for (i = 0; i < 50; )
{
    j = 10 + i;
    while (i < j)
    {
        printf("%d, ", ptr[i]);
        i++;
        if (ptr[i] == 1)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Expected result:

```
50, 25, 76, 38, 19, 58, 29, 88, 44, 22,
11, 34, 17, 52, 26, 13, 40, 20, 10, 5,
16, 8, 4, 2, 1,
```

Comment: Output should be like:
50, 25, 76, 38, 19, 58, 29, 88, 44, 22, ## 1st line
11, 34, 17, 52, 26, 13, 40, 20, 10, 5,   ## 2nd line
16, 8, 4, 2, 1,

Comment: so what *exactly* is the question? How to stop? How to print 40 characters on a line or what?

Comment: I would recommend you indent your code more and give your variables meaningful names.  i is also used both as an index (calling it 'i' is fine there), as well as the current value in the sequence.

Comment: And why should it stop at 4, 2, 1 only? and not the first time it reaches 1, like with `2, 1`

Comment: i.e. you can stop at 4 and print `2, 1` after that

Comment: Note that `printf()` tells you how many characters it wrote.  You might find using `snprintf()` to find out how many characters will be written helpful if you can't exceed 40 characters on the line.

Comment: Output should have 40 characters per line which will have number comma & space and loop should stop when 4,2,1 is encountered in end.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, your code causes a segmentation fault on my machine. You declared `ptr` as a pointer to an integer `int *ptr;`, but you are treating it as an array and storing values into it `ptr[j] = i;`. If you want to put data into an array, then you will either need to malloc a buffer or declare ptr as an array on the stack, i.e., `int ptr[SIZE]`.

A pointer is not a means of storage itself. If you want to have an array for storage, then you need to explicitly allocate an array either on the stack or on the heap.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting it.I am new to C.amended the code as below taking array:
#include<stdio.h>
int main( )               
{   int length;
    int ptr[100];
    int i=50,j=0;
    for(i ;i>=2; )
    {
     if (i % 2 == 0)
      {
       i = i/2;
      }
     else if (i % 2 != 0)
      { 
       i = (3*i)+1;
  //    printf("%d,",i);
      }
      ptr[j]=i ;
     printf("%d, ",ptr[j]);
     j++;
    }}

Output is :
25, 76, 38, 19, 58, 29, 88, 44, 22, 11, 34, 17, 52, 26, 13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1,

Want 40 char per line in o/p inlcluding space,comma & number